# Find any of days is fall under list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-range

I have a table which has two columns ***FromDate*** and ***ToDate***.

Eg.

```
ID  From Date   To Date
1   2012-01-02  2012-01-07 
2   2012-01-08  2012-01-14
3   2012-01-15  2012-01-21
4   2012-01-22  2012-01-28
```

What I am trying to do is when I pass new ***From*** and ***To*** dates, to check against this table to if the new date range fall under any of this dates finding the associate `ID` value. (I am not passing the exact from and Todate values which are already in the table)

For example if I pass `2012/01/25` as From and `2012/02/03` as To Date it should return 4.

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      to_date   >= @from_date_parameter
  AND from_date <= @to_date_parameter
```

Comment: +1 : Thanks. hims056 was 1 min early :)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - Actually, 1 min later.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable
WHERE FromDate<= '2012/02/03' AND ToDate>= '2012/01/25'
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55207/2)

Comment: Should be `AND` rather than `OR`.  If the data hold the record `2099-01-01 to 2099-12-31`, they are both `>= '2012/01/25'` and so pass your current test...

Comment: +1 : Dems was early actually !!